# Can i assign 2 state out of bound accessed bits to 4 state variable?

Tags: system-verilog, iverilog

Should this produce x or 0 and thus the result be completely x or 0? Acc. to LRM if we access 2 state variable  out of bound then it should be 0. Is it correct to assign 0 to r2.

```
module top;
    reg [1:0] r;
    bit [1:0] b;

    assign  r2= b[2:1] + b[3:2]; 
    initial begin
       $monitor(r2);
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: I have tried this on 4 simulators. 3 return 0; 1 returns an X. I don't know which is correct: the LRM gives an example using the `logic` type, but not the `bit` type as far as I can see.

Comment: I say I don't know which is correct, because it doesn't seem to be clear in the LRM (but I didn't read all 1275 pages!). I teach that an out-of-range index on an array returns the default value for the type, making 0 correct and X wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Reading from [IEEE 1800-2012 Section 11.5.1](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html):

> The bit can be addressed using an expression that shall be evaluated
>   in a self-determined context. **If the bitselect address is invalid**
>   (it is *out of bounds* or has one or more x or z bits), **then the
>   value returned by the reference shall be x for 4-state and 0 for
>   2-state values**. A bit-select or part-select of a scalar, or of a
>   real variable or real parameter, shall be illegal.

As mentioned in the LRM, **the result of out-of-bound selection should be default value**. In your case of **two state** variable (*bit*), the value should be **zeroed out**.

The [VCS 2017 migration guide](https://solvnet.synopsys.com/retrieve/customer/application_notes/attached_files/2626632/VCS_VCSMX_Migration_Doc_1703.pdf) also has bug fixes for bit select for parameters. I tried out the following code and found satisfactory results with a latest simulator:

```
module top;
    reg [1:0] r2;
    bit [1:0] b;

    assign  r2= b[2:1] + b[3:2]; 
    initial begin
      b = 1;
      #1;
      $display("r2 = %b b[3:2] = %b", r2,b[3:2]);
    end

endmodule
```

Note that the example is ran on different versions of simulator. Other simulators can behave differently.

> **Output VCS 2017**:
>
> bit [1:0] r2; bit [1:0] b; // --> r2 = 00 b[3:2] = 00
>
> reg [1:0] r2; bit [1:0] b; // --> r2 = 00 b[3:2] = 00. VCS 2014 is having a bug where it is solving this equation with 4 state value.
>
> bit [1:0] r2; reg [1:0] b; // --> r2 = 00 b[3:2] = xx. Here the x is optimized to the default value of bit.
>
> reg [1:0] r2; reg [1:0] b; //--> r2 = xx b[3:2] = xx

Note that the result is always expected as 'x' when we are using part-select itself as 'x'.

> A part-select that addresses a range of bits that are completely out
>   of the address bounds of the vector, packed array, packed structure,
>   parameter or concatenation, or a part-select **that is x or z shall
>   yield the value x when read** and shall have no effect on the data
>   stored when written.

The above one is again from same section from LRM.